# HSQL database storage format

Tags: hsqldb

I am just starting usage of HSQL database and I'm misunderstanding storage format of data.
I have made simple test program creating entity via Hibernate. I used file-based standalone in-process mode of HSQL.
I got this file of data:
testdb.script

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB52B647B0B4
// SET DATABASE lines skipped

INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(1,'Peter','UUU')
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(2,'Nasta','Kuzminova')
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(3,'Peter','Sagan')
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(4,'Nasta','Kuzminova')
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(5,'Peter','Sagan')
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(6,'Nasta','Kuzminova')
```

As I understand when I get a lot of data, all of it will be stored as such SQL script and executed every time of database startup and will be kept in memory?

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT statements in the `.script` file are for MEMORY tables of the database.

If you create a table with `CREATE CACHED TABLE ...` or you change a MEMORY table to CACHED with `SET TABLE <name> TYPE CACHED` the data for the table will be stored in the `.data` file and there will be no INSERT statements in the `.script`. file.